# How we can monitor users activity on SharePoint online without external analytics?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, office-integration

How can we monitor users activity on SharePoint online pages, such as watching a video or viewing PowerPoint or pdf or reading content on pages and also times that users stay in specific page? I want to do this without any external analytics ?

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Please remember to accept the helpful answer if you resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using Microsoft 365 Reports in the admin center, you will be able to get different kind report.

User with admin permission can see this report.

Below are the steps to check the report.

1. In the admin center, go to the Reports > Usage page.
2. Click the View more button from the at-a-glance activity card for a
   service (such as email or OneDrive) to see the report detail page.
   In there different reports for the service are provided in tabs.

Refer this Microsoft docs for more details.

- [Sort video on O365 report](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/activity-reports/activity-reports?view=o365-worldwide#watch-act-on-a-usage-report-in-office-365)

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you could go to Microsoft 365 admin center -> Microsoft 365 compliance -> Audit -> Check Audit logs.